# Toggle single Div layer using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At runtime I have a loop that creates a number of `div`s with the same class depending on the number in the database.

```
<div class="show">....</div> 
<div class="show">....</div>  
<div class="show">....</div>
```

I want to display this div using the `slideToggle()` function with jQuery. For each of these I have a separate hyperlink which when clicked should display the div. Also there are a number of tags in between the hyperlink and the div that I want to toggle.

```
<div>
<div>
<a href="#" class="display">View</a>  

</div>
    <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>


<div class="show">....</div>

<div>
<div>    
<a href="#" class="display">View</a>  
</div>
    <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>



<div class="show">....</div> 

<div>
<div>
<a href="#" class="display">View</a>  

</div>
    <br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>


<div class="show">....</div>   

$(function () {    
     $(".display").click(function(){    
         $(".show").slideToggle();    
         return false;     
      });  
});
```

Naturally when this is called each div layer is toggled, regardless of which hyperlink is clicked. I want to just toggle the div closest to the given hyperlink.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `<div>` relatively by going from `this` using [tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), like this:

```
$(function () {
  $(".display").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

In this case since it's the next sibling element we care about, use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), if the structure is different from the question, you'll need to adjust it accordingly, go get from the `<a>` you clicked on (`this`) to the `<div>` you want to toggle.

Comment: Actually .next("div") is more safe in case there is something in the middle. @Barry - You can mess around with this here if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/zDgQ2/

Comment: @Shadow - `.next("div")` won't work if there's something in the middle, `.next()` finds the next sibling *if* it matches the selector, not *until* it matches the selector, you would need `.nextAll("div:first")` for that :)

Comment: @Nick - sorry, didn't know that.. pretty new to jQuery myself so still learning. Thanks for clearing this out. :-)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I just edited it there to show the actual tags in between the hyperlink and the div. Thanks

Comment: @Barry - please paste you code as-is, then click the `010101` button to tab it over 4 spaces, this will give you nice formatting...as it is right now I can't tell what your structure looks like.

Comment: Hi Nick, I think have done that now. I'm new to stack overflow. Sorry if its unreadable. There a number of tags in between the div that I want to toggle and the hyperlink that calls the javascript function.

Comment: @Barry - I still don't follow your structure, you have far more `</div>` tags than `<div>` tags... it *seems* you just need `.prev()` instead of `.next()`, or I have it backwards

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  $(".display").click(function () {
  $(this).next.(".show").slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or while you loop through creating your divs, can you add (for example) a rel value that's incremented by one every time? Giving you something like...

```
<a href="#" class="display" rel="1">View</a>
<div class="show" rel="1">....</div>
<a href="#" class="display" rel="2">View</a>
<div class="show" rel="2">....</div>
<a href="#" class="display" rel="3">View</a>
<div class="show" rel="3">....</div>
```

This would then link the two divs so that you could get the rel value of your clicked element and use that to identify the shown / hidden div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$(".display").click(function () {
var element_id = $(this).attr('rel');
$(".show").attr('rel', element_id).slideToggle();
return false;
});
});
```